# custom user provider in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am trying to configure a custom user provider in synfony 2 to create a login mechanism using the DB as a storage system. Just as the tutorial says I have added this definition to my security.xml

```
  <provider name="in_db">
     <entity class="Nourdine\BusinessBundle\Entity\AuthenticatedUser" property="username" />
  </provider>
```

unfortunately this break everything and I get a nasty:

> InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "entity" under
>   "security.providers.in_db"

What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which tutorial are you following?

The official cookbook is recommended: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html

In your security config, you are giving the User class as a provider.  Big difference.

Your UserProvider needs to be a service.  You then provide it's service id under providers.

Unless you are trying to use the AuthenticatedUser's repository?